# Best way to create a 7 by 7 reflowable grid/table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking into making a grid/table of 49 divs/cells (representing numbers) rendered in a grid  of max 7 rows by 7 columns when there is enough space, but reflowable to more rows and less columns or more columns and less rows depending on the room it has in the view.

What would be the best/easiest/recommended way to make this?

Looking into pure html/css solution, no 3rd party library.

EDIT:

I have a main div with all the 49 numbered divs inside the main. I added a `float: left` attribute, which seems to take me in the right direction. however, I want a max of 7 columns when there is enough space for them, and decrease the number of columns when there is not.

Comment: i.e. http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using flex, and adding a max-width attribute to the main div of the sum of 7 of the numbered divs inside.